# How to introduce each element of an array into existing divs, by order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have one array with 4 elements and also 4 divs.

```js
array = [a, b, c, d]
```

```html
<div class="introduce-data-here"></div>
<div class="introduce-data-here"></div>
<div class="introduce-data-here"></div>
<div class="introduce-data-here"></div>
```

How do I insert the "a" from the array into the first div, then the "b" into the second div and so on and so on.

This is what I expect to have:

```html
<div class="introduce-data-here">a</div>
<div class="introduce-data-here">b</div>
<div class="introduce-data-here">c</div>
<div class="introduce-data-here">d</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **introduce**? do you want to insert text into div?

Comment: You can't have multiple HTML element with identical `id` attributes. You should be using `class` there, instead.

Comment: @lucumt Well, I want to create it a <li> and put the a || b || c || d.... inside it.
The important thing is how to track it for getting the correct index into the correct div.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). *"I am trying everything I don't get it to work."* What have those attempts looked like (so we can help with them)? You've said the arrays have the same size, and the divs are created using a `forEach`. You can get the index in the `forEach` callback so you can get the content from the array above...

Comment: Okey @Cerbrus now I have it with class, how do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way by which you can achieve this requirement.

```js
const divArray = ['div1', 'div2', 'div3', 'div4'];
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

divArray.forEach((item, index) => {
   let divEl = document.createElement('div');
   divEl.className = "lorem-ipsum";
   divEl.innerHTML = arr[index];
   document.getElementById('result').appendChild(divEl);
})
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Definitely implementing it like this on my app! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way of doing it:

```js
const data = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

let a=data.slice(0);
document.querySelectorAll(".lorem-ipsum").forEach(div=>div.textContent=a.shift())
```

```html
<div class="lorem-ipsum"></div>
<div class="lorem-ipsum"></div>
<div class="lorem-ipsum"></div>
<div class="lorem-ipsum"></div>
```